# How to get branches using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, .net, git, version-control, libgit2sharp

I have a git url like `git@test-git-server:product/test-product.get` which contains 2 branches. I want to get every branch associated with that url.

I tried getting information from location directory cloned from that url but it shows only main branch.

```
var repo = new Repository(path);

var remotes = repo.Network.Remotes;

foreach (var remote in remotes)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("remote: {0}", remote.Name);
}
```

How to do this using LibGit2Sharp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the `Branches` property in `Repository`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Lookup and enumerate branches in the repository.
/// </summary>
public BranchCollection Branches
```

Source: Line 283 in here: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp/Repository.cs

Comment: The problem is when I create a new branch on git, I cannot get that new branch information from Branches property.

Comment: I also cannot get branches from git url both http and ssh. Please help me if you know how to do it.

Comment: It does not throw an error but does not show a new branch. I have to fetch from the server to get up-to-date information like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22013200/53261.