# How to fetch change from Git using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, .net, git, version-control, libgit2sharp

The code below clone a Git url to a test directory.

```
var url = @"http://abc-555.com/team/project-555.git";
var path = @"E:\temp_555";

var credential =  new Credentials() { Username = "a8888", Password="88888888"};
var clonePath = Repository.Clone(url, path, credentials: credential);

using (var repo = new Repository(clonePath))
{
    foreach (var branch in repo.Branches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(branch.Name);
    }

    // somebody creates a new branch here, so I want to fetch it.
    repo.Fetch("origin");

    foreach (var branch in repo.Branches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(branch.Name);
    }
}
```

I want to fetch a new branch before merging it to local Git. Anyway, it throws `An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error). Request failed with status code: 401` exception.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specifiy the credentials to be used through a **[FetchOptions](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/FetchOptions.cs)** instance as the last parameter of the `Fetch` call.

```
repo.Fetch("origin", new FetchOptions { Credentials = credential});
```

Comment: This API is obsolete, use [CredentialsProvider instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26177459/305092)